# SQL "over" partition WHERE date between two values

Tags: sql, partitioning

I have a query that partitions and ranks "Note" records, grouping them by ID_Task (users add notes for each task).  I want to rank the notes by date, but I also want to restrict it so they're ranked between two dates.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.  So far my SELECT looks like this:

```
SELECT  Note.ID, 
        Note.ID_Task, 
        Note.[Days], 
        Note.[Date], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Task ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE), Edited ASC) AS Rank
        FROM
        Note
        WHERE
        Note.Locked = 1 AND Note.Deleted = 0
```

Now, I assume that if I put the WHERE clause at the bottom, although they'll still have ranks, I might or might not get item with rank 1, as it might get filtered out.  So is there a way I can only partition records WHERE , ignoring all of the others?  I could partition a sub-query I guess.

The intention is to use the rank number to find the most recent note for each task, in another query.  So in that query I'll join with this result WHERE rank = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row_number()` operates *after* `where`.  You'll always get a row 1.

For example:

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert @t values (3), (1), (4)
select  row_number() over (order by id)
from    @t
where   id > 1
```

This prints:

```
1
2
```

Comment: It does?  That's great news.  Thanks.